# Terraform Azure rule recreates firewall rule every time I run plan or apply

Tags: terraform, firewall, terraform-provider-azure

I have a Terraform module which creates a SQL server and firewall rules in Azure

```bash
resource "azurerm_sql_server" "sqlServer" {
    name = "sql-server"
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resourceGroup.name
    location = var.location
    version = "12.0"
    administrator_login = ""
    administrator_login_password = ""
}
resource "azurerm_sql_database" "sqlDatabase" {
    name = "DbName"
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resourceGroup.name
    location = var.location
    server_name = azurerm_sql_server.sqlServer.name
    ...
}

resource "azurerm_sql_firewall_rule" "firewall" {
  name = "firewall"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resourceGroup.name
  server_name = azurerm_sql_server.sqlServer.name
  start_ip_address = "0.0.0.0"
  end_ip_address = "0.0.0.0"
}
```

Each time I run plan or apply, Terraform is trying to create these firewall rules (without destroying the old ones).
Output:

```bash
  # azurerm_sql_firewall_rule.firewall will be created
  + resource "azurerm_sql_firewall_rule" "firewall" {
      + end_ip_address      = "0.0.0.0"
      + id                  = (known after apply)
      + name                = "firewall"
      + resource_group_name = "Database"
      + server_name         = "sql-server"
      + start_ip_address    = "0.0.0.0"
    }
```

Its not an issue as the rule exists and if I run the plan, the rules are already there so not created but its misleading for anyone else who wants to use this terraform script.

Do anyone else have this?
Thanks for your help

Comment: what version of terraform are you using?  I was unable to reproduce this using terraform version 0.13.2 and azurerm v2.30.0.

Comment: I've got terraform 0.13 but this also happened on 0.12. Azurerm v2.26. I think, when I apply this, its fine but then I commit the state files and switch branch or computer and the then I get this error. I'm not getting it now because I applied the changes earily. Very weird.

Comment: Perhaps you want to delete this question then,.

Comment: So, I've done some more testing and its when I edit the firewall it shows the above output. But it's not removing my edits. I have added an IP address to it and now the plan shows changes even though "Allow Azure Access" is still "Yes". Thanks

Comment: Is there an answer you can post?

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of all the progress? There should be a line that shows how many resources and changes are deployed at the end.